# I can't prepend HTTP://WWW to the URL when I redirect to the same domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress, cloudflare, openshift-online-2

There is this WordPress application on OpenShift that uses CloudFlare as DNS server.

OpenShift gives us a URL such as `app-user.rhcloud.com` and allow you to add alias. Such as `www.website.com`and `website.com`. So you have to add CNAME entries to your domain website.com pointing to app-user.rhcloud.com. My registrar didn't allow me to add CNAME without a subdomain (without www.) so I moved my DNS Servers to CloudFlare and added the CNAMEs there.

registrar -> CloudFlare -> OpenShift

The WordPress application has a .htaccess to rewrite URL and makes it more friendly. The application configuration is set up to redirect any to a ROOT URL, in my case, I choose to redirect to `http://www.website.com` and this should work. But I started facing a **redirect loop** problem. I tried to do the redirect myself, at the first line of `index.php` file, but it also failed. Then I stopped using the `Location` in the headers to redirect and started with `Refresh`. This was the most effective, but stops working in a few hours. Then I forced a no-cache version as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907653/how-to-force-page-not-to-be-cached-in-php. Didn't work.

I started trying things with .htaccess, checking some rules and conditions to force the  before the application tried to redirect, but it also causes the same loop. The URL never changes, both with .htaccess and with PHP.

I then tried the following: without rewriting URLs **AND/OR** with an empty .htaccess there is no friendly URL, but no redirect loop as well.

Any Ideas on how to solve this? It's been over 2 weeks since I started installing this app, and I have to point non-WWW requests to `HTTP://WWW`

website:
http://www.porta8080.com.br

@edit

Just to make it clearer: I can't add `HTTP://WWW` to non-WWW urls, so it creates a redirect loop. When page is reloaded without the `http://www` it makes the redirect AGAIN. And again and again. This is the real problem.

Comment: How did you configure WordPress?

Comment: it's the default configuration. default .htaccess and Wordpress Address and Site Address are `http://www.porta8080.com.br/`. do you need some particular information?

Comment: redirect-checker.org shows you redirecting non-www to non-www

Comment: yes, because it's not adding the http://www me and wordpress say it to do. the `header()` function and the non-www to www .htaccess are not working. you can cURL and the redirect doesnt include http://www

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting your A record to a 3rd party 301-www host

1) Do it with [CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-CloudFlare-)

2) use a 301-www IP 208.43.88.227 from [Duda](https://support.dudamobile.com/02DudaOne/Domain_Setup/DudaOne_Domain_Setup_with_Static_IP_Redirect)  = `porta8080.com.br IN A 208.43.88.227`

3) check your .htaccess and post it here

4) Also check out the [Wordpress community.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179835/301-redirect-loop)

Comment: i Don't have a unique IP with OpenShift it's shared I suppose, or it can change any day. I just add this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^porta8080.com.br$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.porta8080.com.br:80/$1 [R=301,L]` to my htaccess right after `RewriteEngine On` and check it again... same problem (solution from the link at wordpress community you posted)

Comment: the IP address I gave you ONLY DOES 301 to www, nothing else, I'm actually researching anycast vps, I may just host one for people to use.

Comment: @VictorFerreira Op1(edited) may be what you want.